# Assign Colors to Lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a variable number of lines in matplotlib where the X, Y data and colors are stored in numpy arrays, as shown below. Is there a way to pass an array of colors into the plot function, so I don't have to take an extra step to assign a color to each line individually? Should I be translating the RGB color arrays to another color format for this to work, such as HSV or other?

```
import numpy as np
X = np.arange(1990, 1994)
Y = [[  1.50615936e+08   5.88252480e+07   2.60363587e+08]
     [  1.53193798e+08   5.91663430e+07   2.63123995e+08]
     [  1.55704596e+08   5.94899260e+07   2.65840188e+08]
     [  1.58175186e+08   5.97843680e+07   2.68559452e+08]]
colors = [(0.99609375, 0.3984375, 0.3984375) (0.796875, 0.0, 0.99609375)
          (0.59765625, 0.99609375, 0.0)]
#current way
ax.plot(X, Y)
[ax.lines[i].set_color(color) for i, color in enumerate(colors)]
#way I feel it can be done, but doesn't work currently
ax.plot(X, Y, color=colors)
plt.show()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to use the `Axes` method `set_color_cycle`. As you can imagine, it sets the list of colors that are cycled through when colors are assigned by default, i.e. when no color keyword is provided to the `plot` call. Here's an extended version of your example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(1990, 1994)
Y = [[  1.50615936e+08,   5.88252480e+07,   2.60363587e+08],
     [  1.53193798e+08,   5.91663430e+07,   2.63123995e+08],
     [  1.55704596e+08,   5.94899260e+07,   2.65840188e+08],
     [  1.58175186e+08,   5.97843680e+07,   2.68559452e+08]]
colors = [(0.99609375, 0.3984375, 0.3984375), 
          (0.796875, 0.0, 0.99609375),
          (0.59765625, 0.99609375, 0.0)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.set_title('old way')
ax1.plot(X, Y)
[ax1.lines[i].set_color(color) for i, color in enumerate(colors)]

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.set_title('new way')
ax2.set_color_cycle(colors)
ax2.plot(X, Y)

fig.savefig('manycolors.py')
plt.show()
```

This results in two subplots with the identically colored lines:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of ax.set_color_cycle(). From there I found: mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = self.colors which is exactly what I wanted because I am plotting multiple subplots and need the same colors.

Answer (score 2):

There is still a *newer* "new way" than that suggested by @Yann, since Matplotlib version 1.5. Instead of `set_color_cycle` use (depricated) you should use `set_prop_cycle`. Here you have his example redone. I also recommend you to use [Seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) which has lots of pre-difined palettes where you can chose the number of colours. The palette colours are based on [Colorbrewer](http://personal.psu.edu/cab38/ColorBrewer/ColorBrewer.html), a tool to select good color maps. 
So this is my version of @Yann code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

X = np.arange(1990, 1994)
Y = [[  1.50615936e+08,   5.88252480e+07,   2.60363587e+08],
     [  1.53193798e+08,   5.91663430e+07,   2.63123995e+08],
     [  1.55704596e+08,   5.94899260e+07,   2.65840188e+08],
     [  1.58175186e+08,   5.97843680e+07,   2.68559452e+08]]

colors = sns.color_palette("hls", len(Y[0]))

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.set_title('old way')
ax1.plot(X, Y)
[ax1.lines[i].set_color(color) for i, color in enumerate(colors)]

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.set_title('new way')
ax2.set_prop_cycle('color', colors)
ax2.plot(X, Y)

plt.show()
```