# How to plot color of line segments according to a 3rd value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've gotten the following python3 code that generates line segments

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import collections as mc
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba # https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.to_rgba
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352580/matplotlib-plotting-numerous-disconnected-line-segments-with-different-colors

# to_rgba('violet')
lines = [
    [(0, 1), (1, 1)],
    [(2, 3), (3, 3)],
    [(1, 2), (1, 3)]
]

colors = [
    (1,0,0,1), # red
    (0,1,0,1), # green
    (0,0,1,1), # blue
]

z = [1,2,3]
c = np.array([(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)])

lc = mc.LineCollection(lines, colors=('r','g','b'), linewidths=2)
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)
fig.savefig('line.segments.svg', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0.05)
```

I've been reading through [Matplotlib: Plotting numerous disconnected line segments with different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352580/matplotlib-plotting-numerous-disconnected-line-segments-with-different-colors) and [Matplotlib: Assign Colors to Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283988/matplotlib-assign-colors-to-lines) as well as documentation.

However, I would like to color the line segments according to the index of `z`.  Line at element `e` would have the color set by the value of `z[e]`.  This is like how a scatterplot would be plotted with color as a 3rd dimension.  Similar to this page, https://www.statology.org/matplotlib-scatterplot-color-by-value/, but with line segments, not a scatterplot.

The idea is to set a scale, so that the minimum of `z` would count as one end of the `coolwarm` colormap, and that the maximum of `z` would count as the max.  And a colorbar would be plotted on the right side of the plot, so that the color could be mapped to `z`.

How can I do so?

Comment: pass `colors=np.array(['r','g','b'])[np.array(z)-1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [in the second example of this gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html), one can use the `array` argument in `Linecollection` to be directly colormapped to the `coolwarm` scale.

A colorbar can be added by passing the created line collection object into `fig.colorbar`.

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

lines = [[(0, 1), (1, 1)], [(2, 3), (3, 3)], [(1, 2), (1, 3)]]
z = [1, 2, 3]
colormap = "coolwarm"

lc = LineCollection(lines, array=z, cmap=colormap)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()

fig.colorbar(lc)

plt.show()
```