# colorbar isn't showing correct ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have the following plot code after getting help [How to plot color of line segments according to a 3rd value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77003982/how-to-plot-color-of-line-segments-according-to-a-3rd-value)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
lines = [[(1645, 1), (1646, 1)],[(1652, 1), (1666, 1)],[(472, 2), (544, 2)],[(546, 2), (553, 2)],[(555, 2), (573, 2)],[(578, 2), (581, 2)],[(583, 2), (583, 2)],[(585, 2), (624, 2)],[(631, 2), (644, 2)],[(647, 2), (647, 2)]]
colors = [6.8e-102,6.8e-102,4.5e-82,4.5e-82,4.5e-82,4.5e-82,4.5e-82,4.5e-82,1e-5,0]
lc = LineCollection(lines, array=colors, linewidths=2, cmap = "coolwarm")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20.16, 6.4))
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()
clb = fig.colorbar(lc, label = "evalue")
plt.xlim(left = 0)
plt.ylim(top = 10)
ax.margins(0.3)
fig.savefig('line.segments.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0.05)
```

[image]

I realize that image isn't exciting, but I must reduce it for the purposes of a minimal working example.

the problem is the cblabel ticks:  1.0 > 1e-5.  The ticks are also greater than the max value.  I realize that most of these numbers are very very small, and that most of them are essentially 0.  However, these differences are important in what I'm plotting.  1e-5 and 1e-47 are significantly different for my purposes.  The tick marks are outside of the range that the cmap should be in.

A logarithmic scale won't work either because of 0 being outside of the bounds.

How can I set the cblabel ticks so that they're more reasonably and automatically set and mathematically correct?

or is this a bug in matplotlib?

Comment: Is it not clear that `1e-5` is the offset. The smallest value is 0 and the largest value is 1e-5. 0 is smaller than 6.8e-102. Try `clb = fig.colorbar(lc, label = "evalue", format='%6f')`